# Purpose and implemetnation of json field type in laravel schema builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

what is purpose of `$table->json('options');` as field type of laravel database schema builder.I tried searching hard but couldn't get any relevant info on it.Please some one state list purpose with example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some database engines - PostgreSQL being a major example - have JSON-friendly data types (that MySQL currently lacks - it'll just store as a `TEXT` data type there). This can be handy for working with data (like the `options` example you cite) that might contain a large amount of schema-less or loosely-structured data.

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

Instead of having 100+ columns for a bunch of on/off options for a model, you could store them in a JSON object in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is useful, even with MySQL to store data as JSON.

If you are building an application with user settings, when you only require a handful of user settings for your applications, a few columns in your users or settings table will do the trick nicely. But what about when you have dozens and dozens of configuration options? Well, in these cases, you might consider encoding a bit of JSON, and saving it to a single column.